# TeXLive 2013 manager: Trouble with updating TLMGR (Ubuntu 13.04)

Tags: texlive, ubuntu, updating

Prior to today, `TeXLive 2013` updated fine through the manager on `Ubuntu 13.04`, but now it seems to be stuck in a loop.  I have done this three times now.

[image]

So I have followed this processes by hitting ok, selecting update all installed, and then re-starting `tlmgr`, but it keeps taking me through scenario over and over again.

After I hit ok, I receive this message

[image]

What can I do to get passed this problem?

---

So I determined this only occurs when `texlive.infra` needs to be updated.  When it is just packages, the GUI works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I have found a way to resolve the issue:

If I update from the command line, everything works out fine.  However, the `gui` worked previously.  What I had to do is:

1. `sudo /opt/texbin/tlmgr update --self`
2. `sudo /opt/texbin/tlmgr update --all`

However, I would like to find out why the `gui` stopped working, and I had to resort to the command line for the updates when this wasn't the case a few weeks ago.

As I posted in the updated question, I only need to use this procedure when `texlive.infra` needs to be updated.

Comment: There was `9aug` [tlmgr bugxfix release](http://www.tug.org/texlive/tlmgr-news.html). In any case  command line [`tlmgr update --self --all`  # update infrastructure and all packages](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html#backup-restore-remove-update) is recommended sometimes `texlive.infra` updates may not work on GUI as it's updating itself(I suppose).